# How to tell if a String and a byte[] are equal

Tags: java, client-server

I have built a UDP chat client. To send information from client to server I need to be able to convert the string the client wants to send into a byte[]. I want to be able to remove clients on the server side. When a client sends a certain message to the server the server knows to delete them from the server.

However, when I send the byte[] over the connection, convert it to a string and compare it to the string that will terminate the client from the connection, it never is the same. I just want to be able to get the message sent and be able to tell that the client wants the server to terminate it's log of the client's IP ad port.

Comment: What encoding did you use?

Comment: 'DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);          byte[] dataToSend = packet.getData();                                 message = new String(dataToSend);                                      if (message.equals("Gone.")){} //This is never true, even if message is Gone.'

Comment: @user1504257 you ask about string to byte conversion and vice-versa. Show us the relevant code. Not the code where you create a DatagramPacket, which is irrelevant.

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed people are suggesting you convert to a String when you clearly say you've tried that. As @johnchen902 suggests, make sure you are converting the byte to String with the correct encoding (UTF-8 etc)

Comment: @eldris How do I know what encoding I'm currently using

Comment: When you convert the string to bytes on the client-side you can do string.getBytes("someEncoding"), then on the other end do new String(byteArray, "someEncoding"). If you don't specify the encoding in the getBytes then it will be a default. I'm not 100% sure but I think the default can change. This site might be useful to read through: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html

Comment: and what does buf contain? What does dataToSend contain? What does message contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
String myString = ...;
String byteString = new String(bytes, <charsetName>);

byteString.equals(myString);
```

You can look the charset names [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Convert from byte array to string and use String.equals() method.

```
byte[] b = {(byte) 99, (byte)97, (byte)116};
String s = new String(b, "US-ASCII");// pass encoding here its "US-ASCII".
```

Comment: I tried that, but it never is true. The byte[] value seems to change every time, even though its the same string.